# Pythonで出た結果を新しいテキストに出力する

Tags: python

例えば、Pythonの出力結果で["貴社名","名前","住所","電話番号","FAX"]と結果が出た場合、新しいテキストファイルに入力するにはどのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: 「新しいテキストファイルに入力する」とはどういう処理なのか、ファイルの内容としてどのようになっていて欲しいとか条件があると思うのですが、それを記述してみてください。

Comment: ここを参考に。[7.2. ファイルを読み書きする](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.10/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 1):

用途によっては単にリダイレクトすればよいかもしれないです
コンソール/コマンドプロンプトで

```
python プログラム.py > 出力ファイル.txt
```

などと実行すれば、`print` などでコンソールに出力されていた内容がそのままファイルに書き出されます。